# Call CMD START copy - background zombie process

Tags: batch-file, cmd, call, zombie-process

After running the following script, it leaves behind 4 zombie cmd processes. Any explanation for this, and how can I make the processes exit?

```
call cmd /c start /b copy /y "%VIP_PATH%\*.txt" "P:\"
call cmd /c start /b copy /y "%VIP_PATH%\*.doc" "P:\"

call cmd /c start /b copy /y "%VIP_PATH%\*.xls" "P:\"
call cmd /c start /b copy /y "%VIP_PATH%\*.pdf" "P:\"
```

Comment: Egad!  Why do you have so much preamble for your `copy` commands?  What functionality do `call` and `cmd /c` add to `start /b`?  And you know, you could condense this to `robocopy "%VIP_PATH%" P:\ *.txt *.doc *.xls *.pdf`

Comment: This script is part of a bigger script, so i need this to happen in background. These files are copied into a server, so i would want them to run simultaneously, to save some time.

Comment: Well, yeah, `start /b` makes the `copy` commands non-blocking.  But why `call cmd /c` before `start /b`?

Comment: To run each instance of cmd in its own process, I believe...

Comment: Just do the `robocopy` command, man.  Problem solved.

Comment: Ok, i just found robocopy has a multithreaded switch. Going to try it now

Comment: I'm guessing the zombie processes occur because `call` returns execution to the current thread after completion.  But if there's nothing to return to, if the parent thread has already completed, then have your weapons ready.  @dbenham would be the best person to answer this.  You might post a thread on the dostips forums.  This looks like the sort of abnormal behavior those cats crave.

Comment: Using this inside the bigger script, has something to return to, but still leaves behind these processes. Curious is, that using the same sintax "call cmd /c start /b" for calling another batches works fine.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  I hope, even if robocopy works for you, that you leave this question open for someone smarter than me to provide an answer to the "why" question.

Comment: I found this sintax days ago. If you know anything better for multi threading, let me know. I tried all the combinations with call / start/ cmd, and this seems to be working in certain circumstances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that when you invoke `start /b` with an internal command as argument (`copy` in your case), what gets executed is

```
 "%comspec%" /k yourCommand
```

That is, the command processor is executed with the instruction to keep it open.

Try with

```
start /b "" cmd /c copy /y "%VIP_PATH%\*.txt" "P:\"
```